# Installing an app directly into /Applications/

Tags: ios, sms, sandbox, jailbreak

When you build an app, and directly install it on your iOS device as normal using Xcode, the application will be sandboxed on the device.

However, I would like to build the app straight into /Applications/ so that the application will not be sandboxed and therefore, I will be able to access the SMS database (var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db)

Edit---- Editor
(Editors Fault)

The OP mentioned in his original question that the application would be for a Jailbroken iOS Device, hence the 'jailbreak' tag. Apologies on my (the editors) behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out [iOSOpenDev](http://www.iosopendev.com/) for an alternate toolset to use.

But, also, if your phone is jailbroken, you can use Cydia to install **OpenSSH**.  With SSH installed, and the SSH daemon running, you can just log in to the phone and simply move the application directory (e.g. **/var/mobile/Applications/*/MyAppName.app**) to /Applications.  You might need to change permissions with `chown` or `chmod` to make MyAppName.app and its contents have the same ownership/permissions as the other apps in /Applications.

```
ssh root@iphone-wifi-ip
find /var/mobile/Applications/ -name MyAppName.app
cd /var/mobile/Applications/D76328B1-42F2-4AA0-B1B4-A77796290082/
mv MyAppName.app /Applications/
chown -R mobile.staff /Applications/MyAppName.app
su mobile -c uicache
```

Obviously, the long unique ID string above will be different for you.

Another option is to use [dpkg](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html) to package up your apps, and then install them on the device from the command line.  But, that might be more work than you're ready for yet.

Comment: I move the app to the /Applications/ directory, but, it still can not read the file(var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db).  I don't know what can I do to read the database.

Comment: @Magicfish, ok I just tried this.  I built a normal app with Xcode, signed with my normal Apple developer profile.  I ran it with Xcode.  Then, I performed **exactly** the steps above to move it to /Applications.  It read sms.db successfully.  So, I don't think it's a problem with this issue (how to install an app to /Applications).  My guess is that there's a problem with the code that accesses sms.db.  I'll be up a little longer.  If you post your code that reads sms.db as a new question, I'll take a look at it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with an app that is sold through the iTunes App Store.